# First property inaccsesible of objects parsed by csv-parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-csv-parse

I am parsing a csv file with following contents using [csv-parse](https://csv.js.org/parse/)  -

```
userID,sysID
20,50
30,71
```

However, on the objects returned it isn't possible to access the property created from the first column `userID`.

Here is my code --

```js
async function main(){
    let systemIDs = await getSystemIds('./systems.csv');     
    console.log(`Scanning data for ${systemIDs.length} systems..`);

    console.log(systemIDs[0]);
    console.log(systemIDs[0].userID); // This prints undefined 
    console.log(systemIDs[0].sysID);  // This prints the correct value
}

async function getSystemIds(path){
    let ids= [];
    await new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{        
        const csvParser = csvParse({columns:true, skip_empty_lines: true});
        FS.createReadStream(path)
        .pipe(csvParser)
        .on('readable', ()=>{
            let record ;            
            while(record = csvParser.read()) {
                ids.push(record);
            }            
        })
        .on('finish',()=>{
            resolve();
        });
    });
    return ids;
}
```

Output -

```
Scanning data for 2 systems..
{ 'userID': '20', sysID: '50' } 
undefined  // <== The Problem
50
```

I notice the first column key `userID` has single quotes around it in the console output whereas `sysID` doesn't. But don't know what is causing them.

Comment: Could there be a space in the csv file?

Comment: Also, can you console.log(record) after: while(record = csvParser.read()) {

Comment: @Skarlinski it looks the same `{ 'userID': '20', sysID: '50' }`

Comment: sounds like some weird unicode or hidden spaces issue in the original csv

Comment: I would test other csv's, or add a breakpoint while running with inspect.

Comment: You were on the right track BOM characters generated by excel were to blame

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured it out myself in the end...

I needed the `bom` option. The [documentation](https://csv.js.org/parse/options/bom/#hidden-bom-in-output) states it should be set to true for UTF-8 files. But it is set to false by default.

CSV files generated by MS Excel have a hidden BOM character in them. This gets picked up as part of the header (and key name) by the parser.
Setting the bom option to true makes csv-parse compatible with utf-8 files with or without bom character in them.

Set the bom option when initializing csv-parse -

```js
const csvParser = csvParse({
  columns: true, 
  skip_empty_lines: true,
  bom: true
});
```

---

It isn't very clear to me why this bom character is added to the csv files by Excel. Quote from wikipedia [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark) -

> The Unicode Standard neither requires nor recommends the use of the BOM for UTF-8, but warns that it may be encountered at the start of a file trans-coded from another encoding